# how to get value in json array nested with getParam in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

as the title suggests I would like to know how to use the getParam function to access a nested array. This is my json and my code.

Json:

```
[
{
    "name": "Crock Pot Roast",
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "quantity": "1",
            "name": " beef roast",
            "type": "Meat"
        },
        {
            "quantity": "1 package",
            "name": "brown gravy mix",
            "type": "Baking"
        },
        {
            "quantity": "1 package",
            "name": "dried Italian salad dressing mix",
            "type": "Condiments"
        },
        {
            "quantity": "1 package",
            "name": "dry ranch dressing mix",
            "type": "Condiments"
        },
        {
            "quantity": "1/2 cup",
            "name": "water",
            "type": "Drinks"
        }
    ],
    "steps": [
        "Place beef roast in crock pot.",
        "Mix the dried mixes together in a bowl and sprinkle over the roast.",
        "Pour the water around the roast.",
        "Cook on low for 7-9 hours."
    ],
```

I capture the data that interest me and print them, accessing the nested array via map (quantity values, name, type) in this screen.
Screen1:

```
<FlatList
                        numColumns={2}
                        data={this.state.breweries} 
                         renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                            <View style={styleResult.box}>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.navigate('ReviewDetails', item)}>
                                    <Image   style={styleResult.logo}
                                             source={{uri: item.imageURL}}  />
                                             <Text  style={styleResult.titleRecipe}> {item.name}</Text>
                                             
                                             {item.ingredients.map((v,i) => (
                                                 <Text  style={styleResult.titleRecipe}> {v.name}</Text>
                                                
                                                 ))}
                                </TouchableOpacity>
```

But when I want to bring every single value to a second page via onpress, in screen 2 if I want to print the name I can with getParam ('name'), but if I wanted to print the names of the ingredients, I don't know how to do it.

Screen2

```
const link=navigation.getParam('imageURL');
return(
    
<View style={styleReviewDetails.container}>
  <ScrollView>



  
    
  <Text style={styleReviewDetails.titleRecipe} >{navigation.getParam('name')}</Text>
 
   
<Image style={styleReviewDetails.imageRecipe} source={{uri: link}}></Image>

<Text style={styleReviewDetails.titleRecipe} >Ingredients: ???????</Text>
```

Comment: Do you want to display the ingredients like this `Meat, Baking, Condiments etc` ?

Comment: @dianaqqq yes, i want to print ingredients -> name like beefy roast and brown gravy mix, and relative quantities

Comment: try `this.props.navigation.navigate('ReviewDetails', {name: item})}`  ... are you using latest version of `react-navigation` ?

Comment: @VáclavRyska this.props.navigation.navigate('ReviewDetails', item)} it works, the problem is in page2, reviewDetails, if I want to print the names of the ingredients and I don't know how to do it. For the name of the recipe I just need getParam ('name'), but otherwise I don't know how to move

Answer (score 0):

In your details screen you have an object of the json type you posted.
Therefore, if you want to have a string which contains the ingredient names you could obtain it like this:

```js
const ingredients = navigation.getParam('ingredients') // here you have the list
const ingredientNames = ingredients.map((ingredient) => ingredient.name)

// if you want to put there a separator, like "," you can do it like this:
const ingredientNames =  ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => `${ingredient.type}` +  ( index !== ingredients.length-1 ? " ," : ""))
// in your code it will be used like this

...

     <Text>
        {ingredientNames}
      </Text>
```